# HttpURLConnection catch block repeating

Tags: java, android, try-catch, httpurlconnection, try-catch-finally

I am testing incomplete URLs in AsyncTask to handle missing image and using default drawable for my imageview. I noticed that the stacktrace is printed several times. I worry this is also creating that bitmap over and over again. Is this normal? Any suggestions for handling this better?

Code:

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    Bitmap artistImg = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        artistImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        artistImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
               context.getResources(), R.drawable.question);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "NETWORK ERROR");
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return artistImg;
}
```

Stacktrace (repeated 15+ times):

```
06-24 10:09:49.354  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://i.scdn.co/image/792a417e8500405
06-24 10:09:49.354  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
06-24 10:09:49.355  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
06-24 10:09:49.355  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
06-24 10:09:49.355  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer.ArtistAdapter$FetchArtistThumbTask.doInBackground(ArtistAdapter.java:85)
06-24 10:09:49.355  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer.ArtistAdapter$FetchArtistThumbTask.doInBackground(ArtistAdapter.java:68)
06-24 10:09:49.355  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
06-24 10:09:49.355  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-24 10:09:49.356  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-24 10:09:49.356  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-24 10:09:49.356  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-24 10:09:49.356  21523-21567/com.zosocoder.android.spotifystreamer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: are you instantiating the AsyncTask multiple times, e.g. loading images into a ListView?

Comment: @CSmith Yes, it pulls an image for each list item. Right now I only have 3 items, one of which has a bad URL.

Comment: your list adapter getView() is being called multiple times for that row, causing you to queue up 15 calls to that AsyncTask

Comment: @CSmith Thanks, that pointed me in right direction. I had layout_height=wrap_content for my list view. Changing this to fill_parent resulted in single call for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using either [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load your images. It would make your image loading much simpler. Both of those libraries handle loading images in the background/caching already loaded images on disk/specifying default images in case your request fails while retrieving the image.

Loading an image would simply be:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(imageView);
```

I personally prefer Glide since I find it to be faster but both of those libraries work well and would spare you the trouble of handling your bitmaps manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will definitely check it out. I am working through udacity and Lynda courses for Android and this looks much simpler to use than what I have learned so far.

Answer (score 0):

Android Query

Android-Query (AQuery) is a light-weight library for doing asynchronous tasks and manipulating UI elements in Android.
you can get aquery from here

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.24.3.jar

And documentaton from

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

you can load images from url to your imageview by the following simple code

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(getApplicationContext());
ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
aq.id(image).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll check this out. Much cleaner than what I have been doing.